# Knowing that h is bijective: Prove that $h \circ f = g \circ h$ is a relation of equivalence

Tags: calculus

I understand that a relation of equivalence is that which is:
-Reflexive (xRx)
-Symetric (xRy is equivalent to yRx)
-transitive (xRy and yRz means that xRz)

For the first caractéristic, I think that supposing f=g does the trick (please correct me if I am wrong).
for the second, I tried adding $h^-1$ to both sides...it didn't help.

As for the third: We have:  $h \circ f = g \circ h$ and  $h \circ g = k \circ h$.
Meaning $g \circ h = h^-1 \circ k \circ h \circ h$
Meaning  $h \circ f = h^-1 \circ k \circ h \circ h$
So:  $f \circ h = k \circ h$ thus f=k. And since R is reflexive. Than f is in relation with k.

Please help me prove that R is symetrique

Comment: Hint: do you know any (simple trigonometric) identities that relate values of $\sin x$ to values of $\cos x$?

Comment: @GregMartin yes by using pi/2

Comment: the header doesn't appear to match the body.  In order to show that $\sin \sim \cos$ you need a bijection $h$ with $h\circ \sin=\cos \circ \,h$, no?

Comment: Hmm right, my suggestion was thinking that the two $h$s could be different bijections....

Comment: Should say:  it's not obvious to me that this relation is either symmetric or transitive.  Reflexive works since you can let $h$ be the identity map.  Perhaps you could include proofs for the other two properties?

Comment: Please make the bodies of your MSE posts self-contained. Do not rely on the title to convey important information. In this case, the connection between the title and the question is unclear.

Comment: @lulu alright, I will post a new question with the proof of the relation being that of equivalnce. For as I have rechecked mine I suspect that I have commeted some mistakes. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @RobArthan I think that you are right. I will prephrase the question. And I think it's better to start off from the beginning. Thank you

Comment: I suggest editing this one for clarity and completeness.  Nobody has answered it, so I don't see the harm in a major edit.

Comment: @lulu Yes that is what I have done. I think I will ask about the problem of sin and cos being in a relation in another post since that's the commuinties guideline. But may I please ask you what you meant by h being the identity map? I study maths in French so all that came to my mind is (h(x)=x)...

Comment: I'm afraid that what you wrote doesn't make a lot of sense.  For Reflexivity, it suffices to let $h$ be the identity (that is, $h(x)=x$ for all $x$).  For symmetry, it doesn't look like you tried anything.  For Transitivity, keep in mind that the bijection $h$ might not be the same.  That is, given $F\sim G$ and $G\sim H$ all we know is that we have two bijections, $h_1, h_2$ , with $h_1\circ F=G\circ h_1$ and $h_2\circ G=H\circ h_2$.

Comment: @lulu oh no it's the same bijection. In my assignment it's written: "such as a function h" as for the sets they're equal. E=F(R,R).Do you think I should  add this information to my question too?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you suggesting that there is only one bijection here? Really, what you have written is not at all clear.

Comment: @lulu shgukwugs I think that the issue here is that I myself have not understood the assignment very well... Maybe I should copy the question as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexive -- let $h$ be the identity function.

$h\circ f = f\circ h$

Symmetric -- Since $h$ is a bijection, $h^{-1}$ exists.

Given $h\circ f = g\circ h$
$h^{-1} \circ h \circ f \circ h^{-1} = h^{-1}\circ g\circ h \circ h^{-1}\\
f \circ h^{-1} = h^{-1}\circ g$

Transitive --

There is not a singular function $h$ that defines the relation.  Just that a function exists.  So, when we investigate the transitivity of the relation we must assume that the function that relates $f$ to $g$ is different from the one that relates $g$ to $k.$

If $h_1\circ f = g\circ h_1$ and $h_2\circ g = h_2 \circ c$ then $h_2\circ h_1\circ f  = k\circ h_2 \circ h_1$

Comment: Doug M thank you very much for your answer! But can you please explain the last part of transitive a bit in more detail if possible? Thank you once again

Comment: $h_2\circ h_1\circ  f = h_2\circ g \circ h_1 = k\circ h_2 \circ h_1$ function composition is associative and the composition of bijections is itself a bijection.  $h_1\circ h_2$ is the bijection that relates $f$ to $k$

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for clearing this up! Much obliged!

Comment: Isn't the first part proof that this relation is not one of equivalence? It's not true in general that $h\circ f = f\circ h$

Comment: @David  It is not true in general that $f\circ h = h\circ f.$  However, it is true if $h$ is the identity function.